# Getting TypeError becuase of undefined context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, telegram, telegram-bot, mtproto

I am trying to make a telegram bot using their apis and MTProto.
I imported `telegram-mtproto` into my code and received an error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/telegram-mtproto/es/worker.js (./node_modules/worker-loader?inline!./node_modules/telegram-mtproto/es/worker.js)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/worker-loader/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'context' of undefined
    at Object.pitch (/Volumes/Work/Work/React/Lotteo/loteo-web/node_modules/worker-loader/index.js:32:46)
 @ ./node_modules/telegram-mtproto/es/crypto.js 53:18-61
 @ ./node_modules/telegram-mtproto/es/index.js
 @ ./src/common/utils/initializers.ts
 @ ./src/common/utils/index.ts
 @ ./src/logger/rollbar.ts
 @ ./src/logger/index.ts
 @ ./src/index.tsx
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:3000 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src
```

Here is my code:

```
const MTProto = require('telegram-mtproto').default;
const telPhone = { num : '', code: '' };
const api = { layer : '', initConnection : '', api_id : '' };
const server = { dev: true };
const client = MTProto({ server, api });
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with it after adding `telegram-mtproto` package?

Comment: Can you also add the code you wrote

Comment: Change `require('telegram-mtproto')` to `require('telegram-mtproto').default`

Comment: ```
const MTProto = require('telegram-mtproto').default;
const telPhone = {
  num : '',
  code: ''
};
const api = {
  layer          : '',
  initConnection : '',
  api_id         : ''
};

const server = {
  dev: true
};
const client = MTProto({ server, api });
```

Comment: Add the code into the question perhaps

Comment: @Acidic I followed your guide. But it is the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I am also using the `telegram-mtproto` library.

The following steps worked for me:

1. installed version `3.2.11`. You can get this version via `npm install -S telegram-mtproto@alpha`. See more info about this release here [telegram-mtproto 3.2.11 release note](https://github.com/zerobias/telegram-mtproto/releases/tag/telegram-mtproto%403.2.11)
2. I Installed worker-loader as a dev dependency. `npm install -D worker-loader`.

This two steps cleared all the errors I had.
Good luck!